# create MultiIndex columns based on "lookup"

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I'd like to take an existing DataFrame with a single level of columns and modify it to use a MultiIndex based on a reference list of tuples and have the proper ordering/alignment. To illustrate by example:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10,5), columns = ['nyc','london','canada','chile','earth'])

coltuples = [('cities','nyc'),('countries','canada'),('countries','usa'),('countries','chile'),('planets','earth'),('planets','mars'),('cities','sf'),('cities','london')]
```

I'd like to create a new DataFrame which has a top level consisting of 'cities', 'countries', and 'planets' with the corresponding original columns underneath. I am not concerned about order but definitely proper alignment.

It can be assumed that 'coltuples' will not be missing any of the columns from 'df', but may have extraneous pairs, and the ordering of the pairs can be random.

I am trying something along the lines of:

```
coltuplesuse = [x for x in coltuples if x[1] in df.columns]
cols = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(coltuplesuse, names=['level1','level2'])
df.reindex(columns=cols)
```

which seems to be on the right track but the underlying data in the DataFrame is 'nan'

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things to notice: you want the command `set_axis` rather than reindex, and sorting by the original column order will ensure the correct label is assigned to the correct column (this is done in the `sorted... key=` bit).

```
use_cols = [tup for tup in coltuples if tup[1] in df.columns] 
use_cols = sorted(use_cols, key=lambda x: list(df.columns).index(x[1]))
multi_index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(use_cols, names=['level1', 'level2'])
df.set_axis(multi_index, axis=1)
```

output:

```
level1    cities           countries             planets
level2       nyc    london    canada     chile     earth
0       0.028033  0.540977 -0.056096  1.675698 -0.328630
1       1.170465 -1.003825  0.882126  0.453294 -1.127752
2      -0.187466 -0.192546  0.269802 -1.225172 -0.548491
3       2.272900 -0.085427  0.029242 -2.258696  1.034485
4      -1.243871 -1.660432 -0.051674  2.098602 -2.098941
5      -0.820820 -0.289754  0.019348  0.176778  0.395959
6       1.346459 -0.260583  0.212008 -1.071501  0.945545
7       0.673351  1.133616  1.117379 -0.531403  1.467604
8       0.332187 -3.541103 -0.222365  1.035739 -0.485742
9      -0.605965 -1.442371 -1.628210 -0.711887 -2.104755
```